# ASP.NET Core 7 MVC sending database data to View

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-7.0

The code in my `Index.cshtml.cs` file seems to work as follows:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    if (_context.ACLog != null)
    {
        var aclog = await _context.ACLog.ToListAsync();  <<--
        //ACLog = await _context.ACLog.FirstOrDefaultAsync;
    }
}
```

At the `<<--` it seems to work. Sense this is tied into the `Index.hstml` code, I assume I do not need a return statement. Thus I need to get my HTML code to display a grid in which the code will populate from my database. I have not worked with MVC since at least 2014, so really rusty as to how to write HTML to display a grid function. Any and all help would be helpful.

Comment: "how to write HTML to display a Grid function"  Do you want to use a loop  be executed over the Model which will generate the HTML Table rows with the ACLog records ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to display a grid , hope it can help you:

In **Razor page** you can use the way like:

```
public List<ACLog> Aclog { get; set; }    
public async Task OnGetAsync()
     {
        if (_context.ACLog != null)
        {
             ACLog = await _context.ACLog.ToListAsync();  

        }
      }
```

In the view:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>  @* add your ACLog model property *@
            <th>Name</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Aclog)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In **mvc** you can use the way like :

In controller:

```
public List<ACLog> Aclog { get; set; }    
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
 {
 if (_context.ACLog != null)
  {
    ACLog = await _context.ACLog.ToListAsync(); 
   
   }
     return View(ACLog);
 }
```

Index view:

```
@model  IEnumerable<Aclog>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>  @* add your ACLog model property *@
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Or use Viewbag/ ViewData** to pass the model data:

```
public List<ACLog> Aclog { get; set; }    
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
 {
 if (_context.ACLog != null)
  {
     Aclog = await _context.ACLog.ToListAsync(); 

   }
 
     ViewBag.ACLog = ACLog; 
     // or ViewData
     ViewData["ACLog"] = ACLog;
     return View();
 }
```

Then in the view,modify the above `@foreach` like below to cast the ViewData before using it:

```
 @foreach (var item in (List<Student>)ViewData["ACLog"])
 {
 <tr>
 <td>
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
 </td>
 <td>
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
 </td>

 </tr>
 }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @JoAnn Donaldson , in mvc, you can return the model to the view, then display it.